# Can an entity be an attribute of another entity?

Tags: database-design, erd

For ER/EER Diagram:

I have one entity Stadium and another entity Match. In Match entity I have the stadium as an attribute.

The SOCCER database shall keep information about the stadiums used as venues for the
matches.

Each STADIUM has:

- a stadium id (SId – a surrogate key), stadium name
  (SName), City, and Capacity (max. no. of spectators).

For each MATCH (game) played, we will keep track of the following information:

- match/game id (GId – a surrogate key), game type (GType – see description below in
  item 7), date the match was played (GDate), the venue where the game was played
  (Stadium), first team (Team1), second team (Team2), first team score (Score1), and
  second team score (Score2).

Comment: You may want to edit your question some more, it’s not clear. However I think the answer is yes, you can have a n:1 relationship between match and stadium and you would implement it by column with the foreign key to stadium in table match.

Comment: A relationship is not an attribute.  At least not in ER modelng.  By the time you switch over to relational models,  the foreign keys lk just like other attributes.  Are you usin ER diagrammng to create a picture of a relational model?